# Like button doesn't work every time

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a social media app and one of the features is the like button, unfortunately when you click everything works fine but all of the time it doesn't update the amount of likes correctly and the like button correctly. I believe it's something to do with the refreshing it but I need it to be refreshed so that it can update the amount of likes. Does anyone know what's going on...

```
func like(sender: AnyObject) {

    var buttonPosition: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.table)

    var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.table.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)!

    if sender.currentTitle == "Like" {
        sender.setTitle("Unlike", forState: .Normal)
        var addLikeQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")

        addLikeQuery.whereKey("message", equalTo: self.messages[indexPath.row])

        addLikeQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (aPosts, error) -> Void in
            if let aPosts = aPosts {
                for aPost in aPosts {
                    aPost.addUniqueObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!, forKey: "likers")
                    self.likeDisplayText = ((aPost["likers"] as! [String]).count - 1).description + " Like"
                    self.table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
                    aPost.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            self.likeDisplayText = "Couldn't Like Picture!"
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        sender.setTitle("Like", forState: .Normal)
        var removeLikeQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")

        removeLikeQuery.whereKey("message", equalTo: self.messages[indexPath.row])

        removeLikeQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (rPosts, error) -> Void in
            if let rPosts = rPosts {
                for rPost in rPosts {
                    rPost.removeObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!, forKey: "likers")
                    self.likeDisplayText = ((rPost["likers"] as! [String]).count - 1).description + " Like"
                    self.table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
                    rPost.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            self.likeDisplayText = "Couldn't Like Picture!"

                        }
                    })

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is but i may have some insight. If you are trying to edit some elemts in  your UI through a function that does a lot of processing or is in another thread i suggest making it Asynchronus and anywhere in that function where you are editing UI make that code run on the main thread. Here's what i mean.

```
func like(sender: AnyObject) { 
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) {
    // do background stuff

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      // when you want to edit the text of the button
      // or change something in your UI
      // do it in here
      self.likeDisplayText = "Couldn't Like Picture!"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this it didn't work. I'm not sure what's going on but my like button is just not working at all.

Comment: Use Xcode's debugger and run through the function line by line to see what's wrong.

Comment: I don't think it's that I just think I'm doing something wrong. Do you know any tutorials on how to make a like button?

Comment: You really should learn how to use the debugger on Xcode. It lets you select where in your code to stop the program and lets you go line by line and watch all of the variables to see whats messing it up. Other than that advice i really can't help you. Good luck my friend :)